# Why the set $\{(x,y)\in R^2 ; \sqrt{x^2+y^2}\leq 1\}$ is not a submanifold of $R^2$?

Tags: real-analysis, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

The definition of manifold I'm using is any of the following image:

A set $V$ is said to be a manifold if for every $x\in V$ happens any of the items in the below theorem.

I have to prove that the set $V=\{(x,y)\in R^2 ; \sqrt{x^2+y^2}\leq1\}$ is not a manifold.

I know that the problem is that $V$ has boundary. But I do not know how to argue to prove the assertion. Any hint will be appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hint: take a point $p$ on the boundary. What does a neighborhood of $p$ in the closed disk look like? Does $p$ have a neighborhood which is homeomorphic to an open disk?

Comment: The fourth item is missing.  None of the three shown claim that $V$ is a manifold.

Comment: You’ve only included three of the four assertions?

Comment: I'm just fixed that

Comment: @Malkoun but then I have to use the Invariance of domain theorem to argue in this way

Comment: @Beth, I did not study in the same book. I think it is (at least for me) the easiest to think in terms of (ii) and my previous comment. I am not sure which theorems were covered before etc. But indeed, as you correctly pointed out, the issue has to do with the fact that the closed disk has a boundary. It is called a manifold with boundary. I hope my comments help.

Comment: @Malkoun, thanks. I think that from the Implicit Function Theorem I can guarantee that any point of the boundary must be in the interior of $V$, which is a contradiction. What do you think about that?

Comment: @Beth, you are essentially right. If it is for a course, you may need to add more details. Here is how I think of the problem. A $C^k$ submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^2$ is in particular a topological submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^2$. What is the dimension of the closed disk? It is $2$. A topological surface looks locally near any of its points like an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$. In particular, any point on a surface has a neighborhood which looks like an open disk containing that point in its interior.

Comment: Take a point $p$ on the unit circle. Any open subset of the closed unit disk containing $p$ is the intersection of an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ containing $p$ with the closed unit disk. But then one sees that $p$ always lies on the boundary of such a relatively open subset of the closed unit disk and never in its interior. Hence the closed unit disk is not a topological surface (because of its non-empty boundary, namely the unit circle), and so is not a $C^k$ submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^2$, no matter what $k \geq 0$ is.

Answer (score -1):

Consider $(1,0) \in V$. For any $\epsilon > 0$,

$$\sqrt{(1 + \epsilon)^2 + (0 + \epsilon)^2} = \sqrt{1 + 2\epsilon + 2\epsilon^2} > \sqrt{(1 + \epsilon)^2} = 1 + \epsilon > 1$$

And so $(1,0) + \epsilon \not\in V$, and for any open ball centered at $(1,0)$, that open ball is not a subset of $V$.

Comment: Why this prove that $V$ is not a manifold?